# conditional formatting rules for a cell value - absolute value

Tags: excel

I am using Excel 2013.

I am using conditional formatting on a cell. I have added 3 rules using the highlight cells rules option on the ribbon.

My cell contains a formula. In another cell is a value which is a tolerance level, lets call this value tol.

My current conditional formatting does the below, which is working fine,

```
If my cell is less than tol * 0.8 then colour it green
If my cell is between tol * 0.8 & tol * 0.9 then colour it yellow
If my cell is greater than tol * 0.9 then colour it red
```

However my cell value can be negative and I only care about the absolute value of my cell. When negative my rules will colour it green which may not be correct please see a simple example below.

```
My Cell        Tolerance Level       Outcome I want     My Current Result
75             100                   Green              Green
85             100                   Yellow             Yellow
95             100                   Red                Red
-75            100                   Green              Green
-85            100                   Yellow             Green
-95            100                   Red                Green
```

**EDIT**

I cannot make my cell value absolute. Need to see when its negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the same format for negative values as for positive

```
 If my cell is between tol * -0.79 & tol * 0.79 then colour it green
 If my cell is between tol * 0.8 & tol * 0.9 then colour it yellow
 If my cell is greater than tol * 0.9 then colour it red

 If my cell is between tol * -0.8 & tol * -0.9 then colour it yellow
 If my cell is less than tol * -0.9 then colour it red
```

Answer (score 1):

Create three rules based upon a formula; each using the [ABS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ABS-function-3420200F-5628-4E8C-99DA-C99D7C87713C).

```
=ABS(cell/tol)<0.8                            'for green
=AND(ABS(cell/tol)>=0.8, ABS(cell/tol)<=0.9)  'for yellow
=ABS(cell/tol)>0.9                            'for red
```

Examples:

```
=ABS($A2/$B2)<0.8
=AND(ABS($A2/$B2)>=0.8, ABS($A2/$B2)<=0.9)
=ABS($A2/$B2)>0.9
```

[image: Tolerance Level]